# Monitoring audio while recording it (software mode)

Tags: windows-7, audio-recording, digital-audio

Audacity has such option "software playthrough" but unfortunately Audacity is not applicable for my case. Other software misses that feature it seems, at least I can't find anything that turns the monitoring on/off:

Audition 3, 5.5 / WaveLab 6, 7

Is there a way to hear what is being recorded?

Windows 7. On-board sound card (no input). External ESI UGM96 (not full duplex it seems). I want to record via ASIO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Audition 3.0, go to Options -> Monitoring -> Audition Mix, select either **Smart Input** (to monitor an input only if it's mapped to an armed track) or **Always Input** (to always monitor the input).

For more information, see here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Audition/3.0/help.html?content=WS58a04a822e3e5010548241038980c2c5-7f9d.html

Comment: Thnak you much! P.S. Actually I've found these options in a different place of AA 3.0 - in panel 'Session Properties' (multitrack view only).